# Getopt::Long::Descriptive - Error in option spec:

Tags: perl

I am new to writing usage statements in perl and am having some errors.
See the error messages pasted below.
The beginning of my script is pasted below.

Please let me know if you spot any syntax errors, or anything else I am doing wrong.

Thank you

```
$ perl make_keggTable.pl -i ko2genes.pau
Error in option spec: "input file|i=s"

$ perl make_keggTable.pl --help
Error in option spec: "input file|i=s" 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long::Descriptive;
#use Getopt::Long;
#use Pod::Usage;

## usage and help info
my ( $opt, $usage ) = describe_options(
'make_keggTable.pl %o',
  [ 'input file|i=s', 'file of NCBI locus IDS to Kegg KOs' ],
  [ 'OrgCode|o=s', 'kegg organism code(Pseu.PA14=pau,   Pseu.PA01=pae,Salm.14028S=seo,Salm.LT2=stm,Ecoli.MG1655=eco)'],
  [],
  [ 'verbose|v', 'print with verbosity' ],
  [ 'help',      'print usage message and exit' ],
);

if ($opt->help) {
 print $usage->text, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As perl and `Getopt::Long` follows the option syntax standard of Unix, the option name can't contain spaces. Drop the space between `input file` and you could compile.